# Issue submitting form data from boostrap 4 modal

Tags: laravel, forms, bootstrap-modal, laravelcollective

I cannot get data to submit from a modal in laravel. When I use the below code and hit the 'add user' button, the modal just closes and doesn't seem to call the @store method in my controller. Data doesn't get submitted to the db

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">New User</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {!! Form::open(['method' =>'POST', 'action'=> 'UsersController@store', 'files'=>true, 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
        <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('firstName') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
          {!! Form::label('firstName', 'First Name:') !!}
          {!! Form::text('firstName', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 3])!!}
          @if($errors->has('firstName'))
            {{$errors->first('firstName')}}
          @endif
        </div>
{{--most form data removed for simplicity--}}
        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::submit('Add user', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check if you defined named route? something like this: Route::post('/storedata','Controller@function')->name('store');

Comment: It's defined here:

Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController', ['names'=>[
  'index'=>'users.index',
  'create'=>'users.create',
  'store'=>'users.store',
  'edit'=>'users.edit',
  'show'=>'users.show',
  'destroy'=>'users.destroy',
  ]]);

Answer (score 1):

csrf token is missing in your form, which will not allow to submit data in controller.
Add " @csrf " in form and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your submit button scope is out of the form/div scope or if there is any other button used before submit button.
As you haven't pasted other code for simplicity there must be a button before or issue with HTML tags. Please check all Div tags formatting(opening & closing) or add HTML code here from source code for more help.
Thank you,
Happy Coding.

Comment: The only thing I removed was various form input elements, nothing else. I can't see any out of scope problems. I cannot paste the whole code here

Comment: Is there any other button before submit button?